# Rstudio startup error: rstudio_boost:::filesystem::read_symlink

Tags: rstudio

I recently tried to run an R script from command line that takes input from stdin:

```
echo "print this" | rscript.R
```

The input was generated from a python script. Suddenly, R crashed and ever since whenever I try and open Rstudio I get the following message:

```
rstudio_boost:::filesystem::read_symlink: Access is denied: /path
```

[image: stat]

I have tried to reinstall Rstudio and R, but the problem remains. R runs fine from R GUI

Error from logs:

*RStudio-Desktop\log\rsession-User*:

```
04 Jul 2019 09:46:22 [rsession-User] ERROR Unexpected exception: rstudio_boost::filesystem::read_symlink: Access is denied: "C:/Users\User\My Documents"; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl rstudio::r::session::RReadConsole(const char *,char *,int,int) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\r\session\rstdcallbacks.cpp:387
```

Answer (score 3):

After playing around, I finally decided to delete the whole folder in:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Rstudio-Desktop
```

This fixed the problem. What the origin of the problem is remains a mystry...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to uninstall Rstudio and re-install but it did not work.
I finally solved the issue by renaming the Rstudio folder in:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local
```

After renaming, I re-installed Rstudio and it worked.